c# Bluetooth - Event for Custom Pairing is Not Being Called
I have a Bluetooth device that requires a pin to pair. I am able to discover the device, get services, and read non-pin protected characteristics. The problem I'm having is that I keep getting AccessDenied or Failed statuses for my pairing requests.
I'm attempting to use Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformationCustomPairing and the CustomOnPairingRequested event to pass in the pin. But when I call the PairAsync method the event does not get triggered.
Here's my code. Issue occurs in the AttemptPair method towards the bottom.
    string hardAddress = "70:ac:08:0b:a7:90"; // Device Address

    DeviceInformation etuInfo;
    public BluetoothLEDevice leDevice;      
    public async Task StartUp()
    {
        string[] requestedProperties = { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected" };

        DeviceWatcher watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(
            BluetoothLEDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false),
            requestedProperties,
            DeviceInformationKind.Device);
        //DeviceWatcher watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher();

        watcher.Added += Watcher_Added;
        watcher.Updated += Watcher_Updated;
        watcher.Removed += Watcher_Removed;

        watcher.EnumerationCompleted += Watcher_EnumerationCompleted;
        watcher.Stopped += Watcher_Stopped;

        watcher.Start();

        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private async void Watcher_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine($"Watcher Added: {args.Id}");

        if (args.Id.EndsWith(hardAddress))
        {
            etuInfo = args;
            await AttemptConnect();
        }
    }

    private async Task AttemptConnect()
    {
        if (etuInfo == null)
            return;

        leDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(etuInfo.Id);

        await AttemptPair();
        //etuInfo.Pairing.Custom.PairingRequested += CustomOnPairingRequested;
    }

    public async Task AttemptPair()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Is Paired: {leDevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing.IsPaired}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Pair Type: {leDevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing.ProtectionLevel}");


        DeviceInformationCustomPairing cusPairing = leDevice.DeviceInformation.Pairing.Custom;

        cusPairing.PairingRequested += CustomOnPairingRequested;
        var result = await cusPairing.PairAsync(
                Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DevicePairingKinds.DisplayPin, // Tried every combination
                DevicePairingProtectionLevel.None                          // Tried every combination
            );
        cusPairing.PairingRequested -= CustomOnPairingRequested;

        Debug.WriteLine($"Pairing Success: {result.Status}"); // result.Status == "AccessDenied"
    }

    public void CustomOnPairingRequested(DeviceInformationCustomPairing sender, DevicePairingRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Never Gets Called
        Debug.WriteLine($"Pairing Args: {args.PairingKind} ::: {args.Pin}");

        args.Accept("123456");
    }


Is it UWP app? AccessDenied basically means that your app doesn't have enough permissions

I'm trying to make an app with windows forms. Is there a way to add the permissions?
